# Alternative to the sleep command in PHP

Tags: php, cron, sleep, winlink

I want to display the position of a selection of boats on a page using Google Maps and PHP. To receive position data I use the [Winlink API](http://www.winlink.org/userPositions), where for a specific boat (by callsign) the position data is returned via RSS.

Once per day, a cron-job runs the script, where the position for one boat after another is requested and saved.

There is some sort of request limit and also I don't want to overuse the Winlink server, so I have to spread the requests over some time. Currently, I use the `sleep` command in PHP, but with more boats, I'm facing issues with the max. execution time on my host. I use `set_time_limit`, but thats just a temporary solution.

I thought about using a separate cron per boat, but unfortunately I have access to the server just via iMSCP (a browser-based config) where I only can add/edit cron-jobs manually, and the list of boats should be editable via php, so I don't really know how many boats there might be in the future.

Is there any better way to do what I want?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You run the script once per day and then spread it over the day using `sleep`? You are not making very intelligent use of cron job.

Comment: @Ad Proc: Yes it is, I or my colleagues are able do add/remove/change the list of boats whenever we want, and the position requests should be executed at midnight for whatever number of boats is currently in the database

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: I'm sorry, maybe I included too much background info (I wanted to make it more clear why I want to to it)...Simplified version: How can I spread WinLink RSS Position requests over some time in PHP without using sleep or cron jobs?

Comment: You need a timer to spread requests over time. CRON is the ideal candidate for this.

Comment: I know cron would be great, but I can't dynamically add/delete cron jobs on my server, see above...Thats why I used `sleep` in the first place, but I don't like it...thats why I'm asking here :-)